# Adding and removing textviews from a dynamic list in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been struggling with this for a while now, looking for any tips how to proceed. I'm trying to create a fragment that has an add button, that will create a new textview and when clicking the textview , you would have the option to delete it.

Adding textviews works fine. The problem is in the foreach loop that sets up listeners for each textview and adds the option to delete them. It's forcing me to declare the current parameter final, or the deletion won't work. But if I do declare it final, then I can't add any new textviews to the list, so they wont have listeners.

So if anyone could give me some kind of a hint, that would be hugely appreciated.

Here's the list and the adding part.

```html
//Variables
List<TextView> TextViews = new ArrayList<TextView>();

            @Override
            //Put button functionality here
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
                final LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder.setTitle("Title");

                // Set up the input/
                final EditText input = new EditText(getContext());
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                builder.setView(input);
                
                // Set up the buttons
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        notesIndex = new Integer(notesIndex + 1);
                        noteText = input.getText().toString();
                        TextView a = new TextView(view.getContext());
                        a.setText(noteText);
                        a.setHeight(150);
                        a.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        myLayout.addView(a);
                        TextViews.add(a);
                        noteTexts.add(noteText);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                builder.show();
```

And here is the foreach loop that sets up listeners for each TextView. They are both called in OnCreateView.

```
    for (final TextView current : TextViews) {
        current.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder.setTitle("Delete?");

                // Set up the buttons
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        myLayout.removeView(current);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                builder.show();

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         // Set up the buttons


         builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                           addViewToLayout();
                        }
                    });

        void addViewToLayout(){
    notesIndex = new Integer(notesIndex + 1);
                        noteText = input.getText().toString(); 
         TextView a = new TextView(view.getContext());
                              a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                       showAlertToDelete(v)
                }
    });
                        a.setText(noteText);
                        a.setHeight(150);
                        a.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        myLayout.addView(a);
                        TextViews.add(a);
                        noteTexts.add(noteText);

        }

void showAlertToDelete(View v){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder.setTitle("Delete?");

                // Set up the buttons
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        myLayout.removeView(v);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                builder.show();
}
```